# How to dequeue a linked list with O(1) performance?

Tags: python, linked-list, queue, nodes, deque

```
    """dequeues item, removing first item from front NodeList
    If front NodeList is empty, remove items from rear NodeList
    and add to front NodeList until rear NodeList is empty
    If front NodeList and rear NodeList are both empty, raise IndexError
    Must be O(1) - general case"""
```

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, value: Any, rest: Optional[Node]):
        self.value = value      # value
        self.rest = rest        # NodeList

class Queue:
    def __init__(self, rear: Optional[Node] = None, front: Optional[Node] = None, num_items: int = 0):
        self.rear = rear    # rear NodeList
        self.front = front   # front NodeList
        self.num_items = num_items  # number of items in Queue
```

I'm confused as to how I could create an O(1) dequeue() function that removes the innermost Node.

For example, dequeuing Queue(Node(2, Node(1)), None) should result in the queue: Queue(None, Node(2, None)), where the front of the Queue is Node(2, None).

Because the function should have O(1) performance, I don't see how I could access Node(1, None) without removing its parent nodes. I could only remove the "outermost" Node, such that dequeuing Queue(Node(2, Node(1, None)) results in Queue(Node(1, None)) by setting Queue.front = Queue.front.rest.

I hope this makes sense. This is my first time posting on StackOverflow, so I know my post may be a bit unclear. Please let me know if any details are wrong.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "innermost node"?

Comment: @BrokenBenchmark Sorry - I mean to refer to the last Node of the linked list, containing "None" as its .rest attribute.

Comment: What do you mean with "general case"?

Comment: @BrokenBenchmark Regarding your answer (and the question): The instructions say "remove items from rear NodeList and add to front NodeList **until** rear NodeList is empty". I.e., they shall write a loop. That's O(1) amortized/average, which is probably what "general case" is supposed to mean.

Comment: @KellyBundy I assume it's referring to the fact that dequeue() will only take in a linked list consisting of Nodes.

Comment: @EggDev No, it has access to *two* lists, both front and rear.

Comment: @KellyBundy I am confused on whether or not that would count as O(1) performance. I didn't receive any instructions to have any loops in queueing and dequeuing. In my original code, I just set NodeList.rear equal to NodeList.front. Is this possibly wrong?

Comment: As I said: The "until" suggests a loop (a `while` loop). It seems you don't understand the purpose of the two lists. It's a classic. I suggest you search for `implement a queue with two stacks`.

Comment: @KellyBundy Okay, I see which parts I'm missing and where my confusion lies. I'll look more into that, thank you.